# Rails app slow after PostgreSQL inactivity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using Rails with PostgreSQL and I often get these 504 gateway timeouts (30+ secs) seemingly out of nowhere. I just noticed that this usually happens after my database has been inactive (like half a day or so). After feeding my app some new content via its JSON API, speeds immediately return to normal (2-3 secs). How can this be?

Are my PostgreSQL workers going dormant somehow? Do I need a cron script to act as a little ping pong ball bouncing back and forth making sure everybody's awake?

Prior to all of this I've:

- made sure I'm not querying any 3rd party services
- confirmed it's not Nginx, Puma, or my network in general
- looked for clues with rack-mini-profiler
- confirmed it's not the "initial request" problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12903611

Comment: is you app running in heroku or similar service?

Comment: Any database will have a connection timeout which you can configure. While you could set this very large, you'd probably find yourself getting too many dead connections building up. The usual approach is to check the connection when you check it out of the pool (usually by sending SELECT 1 and checking if it responds, replacing it with a new connection if it does not). I don't know what the ruby approach is to this, but I'd expect you'd find an option in the pool's configuration. Or if your app is super-low-traffic, a connection pool may not be needed at all.

Comment: @Aguardientico nope, DigitalOcean.

Comment: @Dave cool. Something like http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer maybe?